# How to replace the browse button with the selected file path in jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a table which contains a row the browses button and text box.

If you click on browse button and select a file then it will show you the path of the file besides the browse button, but I want to replace the browse button with the selected file path.

Can any one resolve this?

You can check out @ http://jsfiddle.net/AGSt5/1/

```
 <html>
 <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4 /jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    $clone_row = $('#FirstRow').clone(true);
    $clone_row.appendTo('#listfiles');
    var row_len = $('#listfiles tr').length;
    var file_name = 'File ' + row_len + ':';
    $clone_row.find('span.file_name').text(file_name);

   });
   });

   function deleteRow(btn) {
    $(btn).parent().parent().remove();
  $('#listfiles tr').each(function (i) {
    var index = i + 1;
    $('td:first .file_name', this).text('File ' + index + ':');
   })
 }
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
 <table id="listfiles">
 <tr id="FirstRow">
    <td>    <span class="file_name">File 1:</span>

        <input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" value="xyz" />Description:
        <input type="text" name="description" id="filename" value="" />
        <a href="#" onclick="deleteRow(this);">DeleteFile</a>

    </td>

 </tr>
 </table> <a href="#" id="btnAdd">Add additional file</a> 
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: hey thank you for correcting my question but can you please do the needful....

Answer (score 0):

Like this? Note I had to change to a higher version of jQuery - also you may want to remove the fakepath and you MUST change the IDs so they are unique

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uq2yx/)

```
$(function () {
  var $firstRow = $(".Row").first().clone(true);
  $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    $clone_row = $firstRow.clone(true);
    $clone_row.find("input").val("");
    $clone_row.appendTo('#listfiles');
    var row_len = $('#listfiles tr').length;
    var file_name = 'File ' + row_len + ':';
    $clone_row.find('span.file_name').text(file_name);

});
$(".fileUpload").on("change",function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).after($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: no problem,,,,any version of jquery ok for me...but look at your live demo once....after you select a file by clicking on browse button and then if you press add additional link then it is bringing the same row with same file location but if whenever you press add additional button the new row should come without any values just empty....